what pipeline stages corresponds to what presentation engine work when using synchronization primitives?
Links that explain my question better: Vulkan tutorial(Subpass dependencies), Vulkanspecification(7.4.2. Semaphore Waiting, the second note)
In the Vulkan tutorial(Link) it is shown that in order to synchronize a pre subpass layout transition so it will wait for the presentation engine to finish presenting an image you can use a VkSubpassDependency like this:
VkSubpassDependency dependency{};
dependency.srcSubpass = VK_SUBPASS_EXTERNAL;
dependency.dstSubpass = 0;
dependency.srcStageMask = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT;
dependency.srcAccessMask = 0;
dependency.dstStageMask = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT;
dependency.dstAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_WRITE_BIT;

But I don't understand why the src dependency as it is shown makes you wait for the presentation engine to finish presenting the image. I would also like an explanation about the use of the dst dependency here.
In general I don't know how can I find out what GPU commands corresponds to what VkPipelineStageFlagBits
the scenario is explained in details in the links above

The presentation engine doesn't have a stage mask. It essentially exists outside of the Vulkan system, acting as an agent independent of all Vulkan queues. But you can still synchronize with it.
Acquiring an image signals a semaphore when the acquisition is done. The batch containing operations that want to use the image therefore needs to have a pWaitSemaphores element that will wait on that particular semaphore. When it does so, it specifies a destination pipeline stage.
That stage is what the source stage mask in the external subpass dependency should be set to, as well as the destination stage mask.

you are right that acquiring the image signals a semaphore(imageAvailableSemaphore) but as the vulkan tutorial said “It assumes that the transition occurs at the start of the pipeline, but we haven't acquired the image yet at that point!”. then the tutorial explaining that we are going do use a subpass dependency to make the first subpass layout transition to wait for the presentation to finish. but i don’t understand how the
subpass dependency as it is shown is referring to the presentation in the src and to the  first subpass layout transition in its dst.

@piplaoo: It doesn't "refer to the presentation in the src". The source refers to everything that "happened before" the renderpass. The semaphore dependency ensures that this includes the presentation engine operation. That is, the render pass creates a dependency on the semaphore wait, and the semaphore wait creates a dependency on the acquire.
